# count modified results of a select in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do a count of results from a select based on 2 of the fields that are returned and I do that with a group by clause. One of the returned fields though I modify using substring and patindex to get everything after a colon that is in the results so I end up with a column containing either the word "paper" or "online". I want to count the number of paper and online results but the results I get do a count based on the original content of the field and not based on what I modified. this is what I am doing right now:

```
select field1, field2, 
       case when substring(field3, patindex('%:%',field3)+1, 6) = 'Paper' then 'paper' 
   else 'online' end, count(field3) 'Count'
from theTable
group by field2, field1, field3
order by field2, field1
```

I also tried:

```
select field1, field2, 
       count(case when substring(field3, patindex('%:%',field3)+1, 6) = 'Paper' then 'paper' 
   else 'online' end) 'Count'
from theTable
group by field2, field1, field3
order by field2, field1
```

What would I need to do to get the count that I am after?

Comment: How did you modify the fields? With UPDATE and/or INSERT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  field1,
        field2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN substring(field3, patindex('%:%', field3) + 1, 6) = 'Paper'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
        END) totalPaper,
        SUM(CASE WHEN substring(field3, patindex('%:%', field3) + 1, 6) <> 'Paper'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
        END) totalOnline,
        count(field3) TotalCount
FROM    theTable
GROUP   BY field2, field1
ORDER   BY field2, field1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5d13/4)

Credits to [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb) for the fiddle link. `:D`

Answer (score 1):

What gets counted depends on the `GROUP BY`.  So you need that logic in the group by clause:

```
select field1, field2, 
   case when substring(field3, patindex('%:%',field3)+1, 6) = 'Paper'
       then 'paper'  else 'online' end 'Type', count(field3) 'Count'
from theTable
group by field2, field1, case when substring(field3,
       patindex('%:%',field3)+1, 6) = 'Paper' then 'paper'  else 'online' end
order by field2, field1
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5d13/3